# Full CSS property table

Tags: css, w3c

Is there a full CSS property table/list?
I need a compact list like this:
[CSS Properties Index](http://meiert.com/en/indices/css-properties/). Is there a W3C one?
The one I wrote is good, but for each property I need all possible values like [line-stacking-strategy](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-linebox/#line-stacking-strategy).

Comment: I'd like to repoen this question or create a new one - it has been 7 year since it was answered and perhaps there is a better asnwer since then. it is still very relevant to have a full list of all CSS properties. It seems to me totally relevant fo Stackoverflow as it is question about documentation for language that widely used by Web-developers: CSS

Comment: I aksed to reopen this question, but this was declined. To not create a third duplicate, here the **current answer for 2019:**  
Meanwihle you can find a [list of all properties  managed by W3C](https://www.w3.org/Style/CSS/all-properties.en.html)

Answer (score 12):

Take a look at [this property index](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS/#indices).

---

CSS 3 properties are chunked into several modules:

- http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-ui/#property
- http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-2d-transforms/#property-index
- http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-transitions/#property-index
- http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-fonts/#property-index
- http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-text/#appendix-f-full-property-index
- http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-animations/#property-index
- http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-color/#property

Comment: it does not have css3 properties

Comment: It's pretty good!... but the one I mentioned has more properties.
Many thx

Comment: Yes! no css3 properties :\ arg where I can find a complete list?

Comment: Added some links. There is no single page with all CSS3 properties, I guess, because CSS3 is still a child (chunked child, indeed).

Comment: There are way too many modules to list in CSS3, with more continuing to be added each month. Finding out which ones matter is an exercise in frustration, and such a list will never be exhaustive.

Comment: This stuff looks really challenging to scrape reliably. I'm looking to obtain the grammars and I had hoped the W3C pages would be more solid for CSS3

Comment: A more complete list of css modules and their statuses is here http://www.w3.org/Style/CSS/current-work

Answer (score 6):

I wish there was a live property list on W3C, or better yet, a an up-to-date API that spits out json.  So far I've been semi-successful scraping from these pages:

- [animations](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-animations/)
- [box](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-box/)
- [fonts](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-fonts/)
- [fragmentation](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-break/)
- [generated content](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-gcpm/)
- [hyperlinks](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-hyperlinks/)
- [multi-column layout](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-multicol/)
- [positioning](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-positioning/)
- [speech](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-speech/)
- [transforms](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-transforms/)
- [transitions](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-transitions/)
- [user interface](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-ui/)
- [device viewport](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-device-adapt/)
- [flexbox](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-flexbox/)
- [grid-layout](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-grid-layout/)
- [lists](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-lists/)
- [ruby](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-ruby/)
- [text](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-text/)
- [template layout](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-layout/)

Comment: I think a good index for 2019 is https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Reference .