# List of all Css properties and allowed values

Tags: css

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Full CSS property table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6187085/full-css-property-table)

Im after a definitive list of all CSS properties which describes in an easy form the valid value or values. It would be nice if the list also stated the min/max number of values for that property, as some are variable, eg border.

EDIT
A few comments have asked why i dont simply try Google or read the w3 specs. The answer to both is i did. The specs themselves while in the whole can be used to determine all properties and values are very long and none are a simple table or complete.

http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/propidx.html

The CSS 21 table appears to be complete and is in the style of the table to reference that i am after. However the other specs do not have an equivalent table.

The CSS3 main page appears to list every single property and is not appropriate for printing. The properties list at the end of it appears to be a delta or sample. Again there is no one big fat simple read reference table.

Comment: Have you [tried Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=List+of+all+Css+properties+and+allowed+values) (yes, that's your question title) and/or looking at the [CSS spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/propidx.html)?

Comment: @thirtydot it would appear that you yourself have never checked the w3 specs. All i want is a simple table that i can print on one or two pages, not something that covers hundreds of pages.

Comment: @o.v. there are multiple CSS versions, the link only has links for v3.

Comment: You didn't say that you wanted "a simple table" in your original question. I suggested that you Google it because your question was three lines long and looked exceedingly lazy. The CSS spec link I gave is not "hundreds of pages", it's a "simple table" containing all the CSS2.1 properties (it's the same link o.v. gave you). In your original question, you also did not specify which version of CSS you wanted. You also did not specify what you want this for. It sounds like you just want a "CSS properties cheat sheet".

Comment: Also, do you want the vendor prefixed properties? `-webkit-box-shadow`/`-moz-box-shadow`/`box-shadow`, for instance.

Comment: CSS3 with its dozens of modules (and counting) will definitely require a lot of printing. Don't start on CSS3, seriously.

Comment: /@thirtydot im after the standard props first, vendor ones are less important, im happy addressing the basics first up.

Comment: To not create a third duplicate, here the **currenty answer for 2019**:  
Meanwihle you can find a [list of all properties  managed by W3C](https://www.w3.org/Style/CSS/all-properties.en.html)

Answer (score 4):

This has already been covered in greater detail [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6187085/1081234)

[MDN CSS Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/CSS_Reference) covers standard CSS properties

[w3 full property table](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/propidx.html) lists CSS2.1 properties

I've also come across [this resource](http://css-infos.net/) - I'm uncertain of its reputability but definitely seems to cover a wider range of properties.

Comment: Great answer. Note however that the two resources are rather different: the W3C document is part of the CSS 2.1 specification, whereas the MDN CSS Reference includes CSS3, too (even experimental features with very limited or no implementation).

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela: you're right, on second look this should be closed as an exact duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/6187085/1081234

Comment: @o.v. the full property table is exact what i want, but where is the css1 and 3 equivalent ?

Comment: If you check the linked answer, it has css3 properties (they are spread out over multiple pages though)

Comment: @mP: CSS1 is pretty easy by just modifying the URL: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS1

Comment: @boltclock I tried all the w3 resources, they are a mess of cross references. Only the 2.1 table is an easy read. V3 is a long read, every prop is half a screen by itself